# Jenkins connection failure when trying to connect via Java library

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jenkins, java-11

I am developing a Jenkins plugin which will be able to connect to a remote Windows machine using a java library and WinRm. I am using JDK 11.0.8, here is the link to the library https://github.com/cloudsoft/winrm4j, anytime I try to connect I have the following error :

```
Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found.
```

I think Jenkins prefers to use a built-in parser instead of using the one provided in my pom.xml.
I have tried to check the problem, for some it has been solved by importing libraries like **rt,** **woodstox** or **jaxws-rt** to the pom file however in my case this solution has not been successful. Moreover I have tried to manually import this package **com.sun.xml.internal.ws** in eclipse but to no avail.

How can I solve this issue?

Here is the full error stack

```
2020-10-15 14:37:50.553+0000 [id=75]    WARNING i.c.winrm4j.client.WinRmFactory#createService: Error creating WinRm service with reflective delegate (trying other strategies): javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
    at org.jenkinsci.maven.plugins.hpi.JettyAndServletApiOnlyClassLoader.findClass(JettyAndServletApiOnlyClassLoader.java:38)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:543)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:90)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:123)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.newInstance(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:101)
Caused: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$1.createException(FactoryFinder.java:61)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$1.createException(FactoryFinder.java:58)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.newInstance(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:103)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:112)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:96)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:112)
    at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.client.WinRmService.<init>(WinRmService.java:44)
    at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.client.WinRmFactory.doCreateService_1_CreateMinimalServiceInstance(WinRmFactory.java:101)
    at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.client.WinRmFactory.doCreateServiceWithReflectivelySetDelegate(WinRmFactory.java:72)
    at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.client.WinRmFactory.createService(WinRmFactory.java:47)
    at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.client.WinRmFactory.newInstance(WinRmFactory.java:21)
    at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.client.WinRmClient.getService(WinRmClient.java:224)
    at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.client.WinRmClient.<init>(WinRmClient.java:205)
    at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.client.WinRmClientBuilder.build(WinRmClientBuilder.java:278)
    at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.winrm.WinRmTool.executeCommand(WinRmTool.java:347)
    at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.winrm.WinRmTool.executePs(WinRmTool.java:364)
    at io.cloudsoft.winrm4j.winrm.WinRmTool$executePs.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at fr.edf.jenkins.plugins.windows.winrm.WinRMCommandLauncher.executeCommand(WinRMCommandLauncher.groovy:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at fr.edf.jenkins.plugins.windows.winrm.WinRMCommand.checkConnection(WinRMCommand.groovy:21)
    at fr.edf.jenkins.plugins.windows.winrm.WinRMCommand$checkConnection.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at fr.edf.jenkins.plugins.windows.WindowsHost$DescriptorImpl.doVerifyConnection(WindowsHost.groovy:226)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:710)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:408)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:212)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.SelectionInterceptedFunction$Adapter.invoke(SelectionInterceptedFunction.java:36)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.verb.HttpVerbInterceptor.invoke(HttpVerbInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.SelectionInterceptedFunction.bindAndInvoke(SelectionInterceptedFunction.java:26)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:145)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:536)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:281)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:694)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:240)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1631)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:129)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
    at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1618)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1369)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020-10-15 14:37:50.562+0000 [id=75]    WARNING i.c.winrm4j.client.WinRmFactory#createService: Error creating WinRm service with many strategies (giving up): javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your stacktrace, Java class loader is delegating to :

```
org.jenkinsci.maven.plugins.hpi.JettyAndServletApiOnlyClassLoader.findClass()
```

which has no chance to load a class beginning with "com.sun.xml." :

```
protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if (name.startsWith("javax.")
        || name.startsWith("org.eclipse.jetty."))
        return jettyClassLoader.loadClass(name);
    else
        throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
}
```

source : https://github.com/jenkinsci/maven-hpi-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/maven/plugins/hpi/JettyAndServletApiOnlyClassLoader.java